# XGBoost classifier shows: training data did not have the following fields

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, xgboost

I was training a model on thyroid disease detection, it was a multiclass classification problem.
So I used XGBoost classifier. I performed `train_test_split` and then I passed `X_train` and `y_train` to xgb (for model training). The model was successfully made.
But when I tried to predict the values by passing `X_test` data it is showing error:

> training data did not have the following fields: age, sex, on_thyroxine, query_on_thyroxine, on_antithyroid_medication, sick, pregnant, thyroid_surgery, I131_treatment, query_hypothyroid, query_hyperthyroid, lithium, goitre, tumor, hypopituitary, psych, T3, TT4, T4U, FTI, referral_source_SVHC, referral_source_SVHD, referral_source_SVI, referral_source_other

So I checked `X_train` dataframe but it has all the required columns(fields).

```py
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x_sampled,y_sampled,train_size=0.75, random_state = 70)

def xgboost(train_x,train_y):
    
     xgb = XGBClassifier()

     # initializing with different combination of parameters
     param_grid_xgboost = {'tree_method': ['auto'],
                  "n_estimators": [10, 20, 30,50, 70, 100, 120],
                  'booster' : ['dart', 'gbtree', 'gblinear'],
                  "max_depth": range(2, 4, 1), 
                  'objective': ['binary:logistics'],
                  'alpha' : (1e-4,10),
                  'colsample_bytree' : (.1, .5),
                  'subsample' : (.1, 1)
              
        
             }
    
     # object for Grid Search cv
     grid= GridSearchCV(xgb, param_grid_xgboost, verbose=3,cv=5)
    
     # finding the best parameters
     grid.fit(train_x, train_y)

     # getting best parameters
     booster = grid.best_params_['booster']
     tree_method = grid.best_params_['tree_method']
     n_estimators = grid.best_params_['n_estimators']
     max_depth = grid.best_params_['max_depth']
     objective = grid.best_params_['objective']
     alpha = grid.best_params_['alpha']
     colsample_bytree = grid.best_params_['colsample_bytree']
     subsample = grid.best_params_['colsample_bytree']
   
     # creating a new model with the best parameters
     xgb = XGBClassifier(booster=booster, tree_method=tree_method, n_estimators=n_estimators,
                                max_depth=max_depth, objective=objective, alpha=alpha,
                                colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree, subsample=subsample)
    
     # training the mew model
     xgb.fit(train_x, train_y)
     print('Best parameters for XGBoost: {}'.format (grid.best_params_))


     return xgb

xgb_classifier = xgboost(X_train,y_train) #the model was trained successfully
xgb_classifier.score(X_test, y_test) # i got score of 0.9456896. i ploted classification matrix, it was good.

pickle.dump(xgb_classifier, open('xgb_model_thyroid_1.pickle', 'wb'))
xgb_model = pickle.load(open('xgb_model_thyroid_1.pickle', 'rb'))

#but when i tried to predict it is showing error
xgb_model.predict([[47.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.,  49.,   2.,  55.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   1.]])
```

Please tell me what to do, what I've done wrong?

Comment: Please provide more details like how you built X_train, X_test, Y_train, y_test and share the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

inputs = (47.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.,  49.,   2.,  55.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   1)

input_data_as_numpy_array = np.asarray(inputs)

input_data_reshaped = input_data_as_numpy_array.reshape(1, -1)

prediction = xgb_model.predict(input_data_reshaped)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I solved it by explicitly passing a dataframe in your last method.

So this:

```
xgb_model.predict([[47.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.,  49.,   2.,  55.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   1.]])
```

Became this:

```
import pandas as pd

row_to_predict = [47.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
              0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.,  49.,   2.,  55.,   0.,   0.,
              0.,   1.] 
df = pd.DataFrame(row_to_predict , columns = xgb_model.feature_names_in_)
xgb_model.predict(df)
```